# MySQL Select all rows from table 1 and all rows from table2 where

Tags: mysql

I have a table (Table1) with 80 rows, I have another table (Table2) with 20 rows.

Each table has a column which contains the same data and its this column I am trying to use to produce a query that returns all the rows in table1 and all the rows in table2, even if table2 does not have a match in table1.

So far I have:

```
SELECT
Table2.SeqNo,
Table2.SeqHeader,
Table2.SeqText,
Table1.UniqueID,
Table1.Room,
Table1.`Status`
FROM
Table1
Inner Join Table2 ON Table2.SeqID = Table1.SeqID
WHERE Table1.UniqueID = (a value)
```

I have tried many different way of writing this query but I am now stuck.

Any help would be great.

Edit:

I now have:

```
SELECT
Table2.SeqNo,
Table2.SeqHeader,
Table2.SeqText,
Table1.UniqueID,
Table1.Room,
Table1.`Status`
FROM
Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.SeqID = Table1.SeqID
WHERE Table1.UniqueID = (a value)
```

When I run the query the result only reutuns rows where "Table1.UniqueID = (a value)". What I need is All the rows in Table2 and all the rows in table1.

Expected result:

```
   | SeqNo   | SeqHeader    | SeqText     | UniqueID      |-- Room--   |-- Status--|
   +---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+------------+-----------+
   |- Data - |-----Data-----|----Data-    |--Data----     |--- Data----|--- Data-- |
   |- Data - |-----Data-----|----Data-    |--Data----     |--- Data----|--- Data-- |
   |- Data - |-----Data-----|----Data-    |-No Data--     |-No Data--  |-No Data-  |
   |- Data - |-----Data-----|----Data-    |-No Data--     |-No Data--  |-No Data-  |
   |- Data - |-----Data-----|----Data-    |-No Data--     |-No Data--  |-No Data-  |
   |- Data - |-----Data-----|----Data-    |-No Data--     |-No Data--  |-No Data-  |
```

This is the best I can do as I don't have the data as in live data because I can't get the query to work as yet.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Use a `left join`. And see [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: @juergend I have changed the JOIN byt the result is still not working, any ideas.

Comment: show us sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: "What I need is **All** the rows in Table2 and **all** the rows in table1." (emphasis added) Then why aren't you doing a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @topshot, Hi, tried FULL OUTER JOIN but that will not work on my server for some reason.

Comment: If you want all rows and not just those where `Table1.UniqueID = (a value)`, then why do you have the where clause?

Comment: Hi all, I think I have the issue cracked. I have used the same query twice with a UNION.The first query using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and the second query using a RIGHT OUTER JOIN. It may not be the correct way but the results are what I was expecting.

Comment: @NirLevy , the where clause is there because Table2 contains records belonging to a parent record in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I see your expected result, it looks like your join is reversed. Try

```
SELECT
Table2.SeqNo,
Table2.SeqHeader,
Table2.SeqText,
Table1.UniqueID,
Table1.Room,
Table1.`Status`
FROM
Table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.SeqID = Table1.SeqID
WHERE Table2.UniqueID = (a value)
```

Comment: Your right. That works. Thank you, that as saved me an extra query. Better than using the UNION.

Comment: Great. FYI, you want the FROM to use the table that has all the records you expect and then join on the table that may have missing records.